# List connected files as array when we call a file with php?

Tags: php, resources, network-protocols

What I am trying to achieve, when I open a website, it starts a network activity by loading images, swf files, css file etc. Is there any way in php to get a list of those resources as array?

Comment: The only way I see this being (kinda) possible is by parsing the rendered HTML page with PHP and look for resources.

Comment: @PeeHaa, Regexs' are a valuable part even in DOM parser.

Comment: @PeeHaa, Well agreed on the failing part. Its hard to match everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The only way I see this being (kinda) possible is by parsing the rendered HTML page with PHP and look for resources. – PeeHaa

You can use [file_get_html](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) if you want to follow this direction

```
$html = file_get_html("http://stackoverflow.com");
$list = array();
foreach ( $html->find("[src=*],link") as $src ) {
    isset($src->src) AND $list[] = $src->src ;
    isset($src->href) AND $list[] = $src->href ;
}
var_dump($list);
```

Example

```
array
  0 => string 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico' (length=52)
  1 => string 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png' (length=61)
  2 => string '/opensearch.xml' (length=15)
  3 => string 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js' (length=63)
  4 => string 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js?v=8a629d6e9fb6' (length=48)
  5 => string 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=d16ae3f98d2e' (length=59)
  6 => string '/feeds' (length=6)
  7 => string 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAGkl.png' (length=34)
  8 => string 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png' (length=34)
  9 => string 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png' (length=34)
  10 => string 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png' (length=34)
  11 => string 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8rHf.png' (length=34)
  12 => string 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png' (length=34)
  13 => string 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png' (length=34)
  14 => string 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png' (length=34)
  15 => string 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QN0y.png' (length=34)
  16 => string 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8rHf.png' (length=34)
  17 => string 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8rHf.png' (length=34)
  18 => string 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png' (length=34)
  19 => string 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmHl0.png' (length=34)
  20 => string 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png' (length=34)
  21 => string 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8rHf.png' (length=34)
  22 => string 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmHl0.png' (length=34)
  23 => string 'http://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel/p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc.gif' (length=53)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a really good idea to figure out the resources from PHP, because you also have to check for external links as well (for example CSS include in any CSS file). Too much possibilities available to handle this in any cases.

However, PeeHaa was right, you have to parse every single file (except images).